# Handling style sheets

Tags: asp.net, html, css

In my application I am using a custom control. This has got one CSS file. The same CSS file with same tags but different definition is included in my application also.

I would like to override my custom control referred CSS file styles with my application styles.

Can anyone suggest the easiest way of achieving this?

Regards,
Kumar.

Answer (score 0):

I assume these custom controls are children of some of your elements like so:

```
<div id="myContainer">

  <span class="customControl"></span>

</div>
```

If this is the case, then in YOUR css, you can override their rules by using a higher specificity.  Essentially preface all of the rules with `#myContainer`

```
#myContainer .customControl { color:red; }
#myContainer .anotherCustomControl { color:blue; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I alreay used # to override, nothing change. my styles are some thing like .ui-widget-header - i just put # infront of the dot (.) . may be i was wrong.

Comment: If you post some of your HTML and CSS I could help more.  Adding the # alone won't do it.  # referes to the ID of a parent element...

Comment: Lets say, there are same styles defined in two different files. how could i make sure application/browser uses the one i wanted..

Comment: I think you need to read up more on CSS specificity.  The order the CSS is loaded doesn't matter quite as much as the specificity of your CSS selectors.  See: http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/